# c# how to load strings from xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file from weather icons that maps a string to an html encoded font string.

I have an xml file that looks something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
      <string name="wi_owm_200">&#xf01e;</string>
    </resources>
```

I need a way that I can lookup easily the string 
    wi_omw_200 
and get back

> &#xf01e

is there an easy way to do this in c#?

Comment: Google XmlReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `XmlNodeList`

```
var xmlString = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
    <resources>
      <string name=\"wi_om_200w\">&#xf01e;</string>
    </resources>";

var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString); 

var xmlNodeList = xml.SelectNodes("/resources/string[@name='wi_om_200w']");
var value = xmlNodeList.FirstOrDefault();
if (value != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value.InnerText);
}
```